# return statement (exam score )) school work

Tags: python, return

I wrote this program but I am having some problem with understanding how to use `return` statement. When I run this program it doesn't print out the result.  Can anyone help to fix this?  I do not want to use `print`.

```
def main():
    score=["A*","A","B","C","FAIL"]
    q=input("what is ur score?")
    q=int(q)
    if q<40:
        return score[4]
    if 41<=q<=50:
        return score[3]
    if 51<=q<=51:
        return score[2]
    if 61<=q<=80:
        return score[1]
    if 81<=q<=100:
        return score[0]


main()
```

Comment: Looks  like you call `main` but you don't do anything with its return value. It doesn't just print automatically. Try `print main()`. Those are pretty generous grades, by the way. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting some output in the stdout, then the above program is missing a print statement. Can you try the following?

```
def main():
    score=["A*","A","B","C","FAIL"]
    q=input("what is ur score?")
    q=int(q)
    if q<40:
        return score[4]
    if 41<=q<=50:
        return score[3]
    if 51<=q<=51:
        return score[2]
    if 61<=q<=80:
        return score[1]
    if 81<=q<=100:
        return score[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the result not return the result. You use return statement when you want to return a result to from a function that is being called e.g.

```
def top():
   return 5

top = top()
print(top)
5 // woul
```

d be printed out to the console

To get the result printed associate the function with a variable i.e

```
result = main();
print result;
```

// print value returned by the function